# How to remove the nearly matches optional requirement warning from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function ios swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift3, xcode8

Since I updated my xcode to xcode 8 I am getting this warning:

Instance method

> application(*:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)'
>   nearly matches optional requirement
>   'application(*:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)' of
>   protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate

Xcode is asking me to silence this warning by making this function private, but when I do the function is never been called (It is not being called in either ways).

I tried to delete the functions then making autocomplete fill it but nothing worked.

This is the function having the warning:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    //
}
```

This is my complete appDelegate file:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    func locationManagerStart() {

        if locationManager == nil {
            print("init locationManager")
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager!.delegate = self
            locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        print("have location manager")
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManagerStop() {
        locationManager!.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //
        let newLocation = locations.first!
        coordinate = newLocation.coordinate
        print("location updated")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        registerForPushNotifications(application)

        return true
    }
    func registerForPushNotifications(_: UIApplication) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
                if (granted)
                {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
                else{
                    //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
                }
            })
        }
        else{
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

        print("I am not available in simulator \(error)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.youcode.Hebr" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Hebr", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After weeks of searching finally solved!
The problem was that I had a class named "Data", it didnot make any error in xcode 7 but whenever i add it in xcode 8 the registerForNotification function in the app delegate makes this error!
Weird but finally solved by just changing the name of the class Data.

Comment: You could also change the type of the argument in the function conforming to the protocol to "Foundation.Data"

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3.0 first parameter names are changed. I think you should add the **underscore** **_** to your first parameters in your function.

Make `_ application:` instead of `application:` as the name of the first parameter in every case.

For example;

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

}
```

Also you can check [this link](http://aplus.rs/2016/swift-3-migration-tip-instance-method-dot-dot-dot-nearly-matches-warning/) for extra information

Comment: Ok please share to me your appDelegate file completely

Comment: And check your all appDelegate functions are they have underscore ? or you can try to autocomplete your all appDelegate function. I think you are probably forget underscore in some your function.